My BottomNavigationView seems to be a little oversized and I cant fix it
I am trying to set up a BottomNavigationView in my app. But there seems to be a little to much space below the menu items. Is there some ways I can reduce it? I added the image at the bottom.
The code of my layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MusicActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</RelativeLayout>

Code of the menu items:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_foreground"
        android:title="@string/Home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_foreground"
        android:title="@string/Search"/>
</menu>

Code for the drawable image assets
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF">
  <group android:scaleX="0.58"
      android:scaleY="0.58"
      android:translateX="5.04"
      android:translateY="5.04">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M12,3L4,9v12h5v-7h6v7h5V9z"/>
  </group>
</vector>

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF">
  <group android:scaleX="0.58"
      android:scaleY="0.58"
      android:translateX="5.04"
      android:translateY="5.04">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
  </group>
</vector>

Image:
Bottom Navigation Bar
